# can I trust apple notebooks or are there some bios level keyloggers from apple/other agency used?

Tags: keyloggers

I need to look for something on deep web but having macbook air, I feel that it could be rooted from apple / reseller - my idea is that there is some chip logging every key stroke and then send it when it can - am I overly paranoid or am I having a good sense of how things now works?

do you believe apple to produce keylogger free no logging notebooks or are you using some alternatives like old PC without intel infected modern cpus?

Comment: If anybody knew that there was malware installed by default by Apple on their products, do you believe anybody would still buy anything produced by Apple? Apple would have gone bankrupt at once

Comment: yes but.. isn't it like with intel cpu - nobody knows that there is top level backdoor.. for YEARS.. and now? people are still buying cpus from that infected company.. nothing changed...

Comment: *"do you __believe__ apple to produce keylogger free no logging notebooks ..."* - how does it matter what we believe? As you said yourself, we've believed a lot in the past which turned out wrong. One can only say if there is a __known__ problem like you describe - but there isn't. I propose to close it as primarily opinion based since the question is all about believing or not.

Comment: maybe I worded that question wrong - so don't be very specific on words :) just wanted to hear some sec experts opinions or what machines are they using...

Comment: @Ondrej unfortunately, this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Questions seeking opinionated answers are usually off-topic.

Comment: We are all paranoid if we are on this information security site, so am sure you are among good company here. Look at [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/96767/188449) 'Use hardware from a vendor you trust more.' . I've got Toshiba and don't even fully trust it, but somehow worry more about attacks coming from software than from hardware, so pay attention to the OS I put on it, and don't worry as much about the hardware. Still I would never want to own a Microsoft device. There are some projects out there to put our paranoid minds to rest check out https://puri.sm/products/

Comment: "Do you trust Macbooks not to have some hidden, undisclosed backdoor/keylogger?" -- this is an entirely opinion-based question and not a good fit on a Q&A site.